# Pointwise convergence, bounded variation, and lim inf's

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf, bounded-variation

Suppose that $\{f_n\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ is a sequence of functions in $BV[0, 1]$ that converges pointwise to a function $f$ on $[a, b]$. Show that $V_a^b f \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} V_a^b f_n$.

I know that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists N > 0$ such that $V_a^b f_n > \liminf_{n \to \infty} V_a^b f_n - \varepsilon$.

I was hoping to get a hint.